# Passing a cursor to ndb on Google App Engine Python 3 leads to an error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

**Note:** This is happening on my development server (MAC running Mojave)

I'm running Python 3 on Google App Engine (standard environment) and I have the code below

```
cursor = ndb.Cursor(urlsafe = next_page) if next_page else ndb.Cursor()
q = myObject.query(myObject.link == linkKey).order(-myObject.created)
resultsFuture = q.fetch_page_async(PAGE_SIZE,start_cursor=cursor)
```

If next_page is not None (which means cursor is not None), I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File .../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/_datastore_api.py", line 92, in rpc_call
    result = yield rpc
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Error parsing protocol message"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"<CREATION_TIME>","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:<MY_IP_ADDRESS>","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Error parsing protocol message","grpc_status":3}"
>
```

Has anyone encountered this before and if so what was the solution?

If not, can anyone point me to a possible solution?

Comment: I've added this as an issue to the NDB issue tracker: https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/issues/471

Comment: The maintainers have some questions for you on that issue

Comment: How do I respond? I don't have an account on Github..  next_page is simply a variable I use to hold the value of the 'cursor' returned from the previous call to fetch_page_async

Comment: No worries, I responded for you. Can you include the code where `next_page` is assigned?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I have the same issue. I am passing it as a URL in my HTML page

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error in the past week and finally fixed it with some help, if you are still facing this issue kindly do the following:

```
cursor = ndb.Cursor(urlsafe = next_page.decode('utf-8')) if next_page else None
q = myObject.query(myObject.link == linkKey).order(-myObject.created)
resultsFuture = q.fetch_page_async(PAGE_SIZE,start_cursor=cursor)
```

This piece of code is really what fixes it:

> next_page.decode('utf-8')

seeing as `next_page` is the urlsafe cursor_string you are sending and then later receiving from your frontend.

The problem seems to occur with Python3 when you create the Cursor from a urlsafe webstring, the issue is, in python2.7 the `urlsafe()` method in `datastore_query.Cursor()`used to be decoded one way or another to utf-8 but in python3 you have to do the conversion manually else what you send and later receive from the frontend will actually be a raw bytestring, mind you, this bytestring will convert smoothly to a Cursor object and even pass test but when sent as a `_datastore_query.Cursor()`, that's where the real problem arises as the Cursor created from that bytestring is wrong and leads to a `status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT` error.

I hope this helps. Kindly let me know if you have any more question on this.

For some more context you can read on the error here:
[GRPC status code 3 for invalid arguments](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/impl_2codegen_2status_8h.html#a35ab2a68917eb836de84cb23253108eba3dd64296110db7e7fafb1062b5587731)

Also you can try logging out the urlsafe (next_page) string you send and receive from your frontend to verify whether it is indeed not utf-8 decoded.

Comment: This answer helped me, but doesn't seem to have it quite right.  The Python 3 `Cursor.urlsafe()` method returns bytes, while the Python 2 version returns a string.  So when sending the cursor to the client, you need to `safe_cursor_str.decode()`, and when reading it back from the client you need to `safe_cursor_str.encode()` before calling `ndb.Cursor(urlsafe=safe_cursor_str)`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/issues/471#issuecomment-649173225 says:

> Hi, the `cursor` returned by `fetch_page_async` is already an instance of `Cursor`. The `urlsafe` argument to `Cursor` is a string that can be derived by calling `Cursor.urlsafe()` on a cursor instance. Since the `cursor` returned by `fetch_page_async` is already a `Cursor` instance, it can be passed directly to another call to `fetch_page_async`.

So instead you should do:

```py
cursor = next_page if next_page else ndb.Cursor()
q = myObject.query(myObject.link == linkKey).order(-myObject.created)
resultsFuture = q.fetch_page_async(PAGE_SIZE,start_cursor=cursor)
```

Comment: Hi, 

There is a misunderstanding.

Yes, I know the cursor returned by fetch_page is already an instance of a cursor. I convert it to a urlsafe string which is then passed to my html page so that use can click on a link with a label of something like 'Next Page'. 

When user clicks on this link, it comes back to the server as the variable 'next_page' which I then have to convert back to an instance of a cursor and then try to execute another fetch_page_async which leads to the error that I reported